# SSRS stored procedure uses RAISERROR causing report to throw rsErrorReadingNextDataRow instead of displaying error message from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

We are converting from Crystal to SSRS. In our stored procedures we have an outer `TRY CATCH` and can have many other `TRY CATCH` blocks.  If there is an error or no data is found, a variable will be set with a message then the outer CATCH will display it.

It's something like this:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRY
        do stuff
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @ERROR_MSG = 'ERROR: There was a problem doing this. (' + ERROR_MESSAGE()) + ')'
        RAISERROR (@ERROR_MSG, 11, 1)
    END CATCH

    IF NO DATA IS FOUND
    BEGIN
        SET @ERROR_MSG = 'No data was found'
        RAISERROR (@ERROR_MSG, 11, 1)
    END

    SELECT DATA
    RETURN 0

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT @ERROR_MSG
    RAISERROR (@ERROR_MSG, 11, 1)
    RETURN 1
END CATCH
```

This has worked fine in Crystal, the error/no data found message displays correctly. In SSRS the `RAISERROR` in the `CATCH` is causing SSRS to display the error `rsErrorReadingNextDataRow` instead of the message.

If I comment out `RAISERROR` or use severity level 0-9 it works fine.

Is there any way I can use severity level 11 and have SSRS display the error message instead of the `rsErrorReadingNextDataRow` error? Thanks!

Comment: If no data is found, why not just return an empty set?

Comment: Just return an empty dataset. SSRS has built-in [NoRowsMessage and NoDataMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/set-a-no-data-message-for-a-data-region-report-builder-and-ssrs) functionality to handle empty results for tables, matrices, lists and charts.

Comment: `SELECT @ERROR_MSG` Stop doing that generally. You shouldn't (nor do you need to) create a 1x1 resultset that contains your error message. Use exceptions to communicate errors to the caller. Learn to rethrow errors, not "re-raise" them. Erland has a [deeper dive into error handling](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html)

Comment: Good points and maybe now is a good time to revisit why we are doing it this way and if it is still necessary.  Thanks for the thoughts everyone!